# Set Focus for component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

This is my code.

```js
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'

if(this.DOB > this.dateOfJoin){
  alert("DOB should not be greater than Date of Join.asd.!")
  this.$refs.dob.focus();
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date of Birth</label>
  <datepicker v-model="DOB" name="DOB"  ref="dob" class="required"></datepicker>
</div>
```

I am using the `vuejs-datepicker` component, but I cannot set focus on the datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through the docs, I recommend a different approach. [The datepicker has a `disabled` property](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker#disabled-dates). This allows you to specify a `from` property that the date cannot be greater than and a `to` property that the date cannot be earlier than. So if you do not want users to select a date of birth greater than the date they joined, set the `from` property to the date joined.

In data properties

```
data:{
    dobDisabled:{ from: <date joined> }
}
```

And on the datepicker,

```
<datepicker :disabled="dobDisabled"></datepicker>
```

That will prevent users from picking an invalid date.

Here is an [example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmlOz_Mvl2bbuCjGgUj).

**Original**

It looks like the datepicker you are using [renders a `readonly` input element](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/blob/master/src/Datepicker.vue#L5), which I expect cannot get focus. In any case, the component which wraps the input does not support a `focus` method.

```
  <input
    :type="inline ? 'hidden' : 'text'"
    :class="[ inputClass, { 'form-control' : bootstrapStyling } ]"
    :name="name"
    :id="id"
    @click="showCalendar"
    :value="formattedValue"
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :clear-button="clearButton"
    :disabled="disabledPicker"
    :required="required"
    readonly>
```

Instead you might try showing the calendar.

```
this.$refs.dob.showCalendar()
```

Comment: Will you plz...explain me with a small demo example